# How to refresh only one update panel which contains legend of highchart not the entire page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

There are two update panel in my code one of them is used for high chart legends. I want to refresh those legends at some interval so i gave timer function. But the other update panel is also refresh (mostly i think both other update panel and the page is refreshing)

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP 1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div id="highchart" class="highchart" runat="server" style="display: block">
                            <HighChart:HighChart ID="reportChart" runat="server" Height="450" Legend_Enabled="true"
                                Legend_HAlign="Center" IsMultiKeys="true" Legend_VAlign="Bottom" ShowLables="false" SubTitle=""
                                Title="" Type="Line" XAxisEnabled="true" XAxisRotation="-45" />
                            <asp:Timer ID="timer1" runat="server" Interval="10000"></asp:Timer>
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I have tried this timer function which makes entire page load